# How to use Collate function in Update query

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework

I have an application with Entity Framework and my database collation is:

```
Latin1_General_CI_AS
```

but my client's database is `Georgian_Modern_Set_CI_AS`. This is a big problem for us but we solved this problem with 'collate' function. We collate our nvarchar values with `Latin1_General_CI_AS` such as;

```
-- with this function we can easily select the data and get into our application.
select Name collate Latin1_General_CI_AS as Name from Users
```

But i have some Update statements and I just want to ask how to use 'collate' function in Update query??

Do you have any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Do  you mean in your where clause?

Comment: @SqlWorldWide it doesn't matter i mean is there any way to use collate function in update query??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
The usual form is:
update
set 
from
where x=y collate 'name of collation'
```

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways you can use collate function during update.

Some of the code copied from [here](http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=73180).

```
CREATE TABLE    #temp1  (
        col1    NVARCHAR(10)    COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS
    ,   col2    NVARCHAR(30)    COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS
        )
GO

CREATE TABLE    #temp2  (
        col1    NVARCHAR(10)    COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS
    ,   col2    NVARCHAR(30)    COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS
        )
GO

-- insert sample data
INSERT INTO #temp1  (
        col1
    ,   col2
        )
SELECT  'test1',    'This is test row 1'
UNION ALL
SELECT  'test2',    'This is test row 2'
UNION ALL
SELECT  'test3',    'This is test row 3'
GO

INSERT INTO #temp2  (
        col1
    ,   col2
        )
SELECT  'test1',    'sample data item 1'
UNION ALL
SELECT  'test2',    'sample data item 2'
UNION ALL
SELECT  'test3',    'sample data item 3'
GO

UPDATE
    t2
SET 
    t2.col2 =   t1.col2
FROM 
    #temp1  t1
INNER JOIN 
    #temp2  T2
ON 
    t1.col1=t2.col1 COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS

UPDATE
    t2
SET 
    t2.col2 =   t1.col2
FROM 
    #temp1  t1
INNER JOIN 
    #temp2  T2
ON 
    t1.col1=t2.col1 COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT 

UPDATE
    t2
SET 
    t2.col2 =   t1.col2 
FROM 
    #temp1  t1
INNER JOIN 
    #temp2  T2
ON 
    t1.col1 COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT  =t2.col1
```

Clean up

```
-- clean up
DROP TABLE  #temp1
GO
DROP TABLE  #temp2
GO
```